# css and html-only burger menu not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website for a class (I can only use css and html, no jquery or javascript or anything) and want a hamburger menu when viewing the website on small screens, and have followed this tutorial (http://codingtips.kanishkkunal.in/css-hamburger-menu/), but have come across a few problems with the menu.. First of all I can't add the menu items to the hamburger span and secondly, the icon is not clickable.. Could you help me figure this out please?
Here's my html-code:

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="sv" > 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<title>...</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_bildkonst.css">

</head>
<body id="Bildkonst"> 
<span class="hamburger">
</span>
<!--following is the regular menu-->
<ul>
<li class=" bildkonst"><a href="bildkonst.html">Bildkonst</a></li>
<li><a class="akryl" href="akryl.html">Akryl</a></li>
<li><a class="fresk" href="fresk.html">Fresk</a></li>
<li><a class="oljemalning" href="oljemalning.html">Oljemålning</a></li>
<li><a class="tempera" href="tempera.html">Tempera</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the css for the above:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.hamburger {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 1.25em;
height: 0.8em;
margin-right: 0.3em;
border-top: 0.2em solid #fff;
border-bottom: 0.2em solid #fff;
}

.hamburger:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0.3em;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
border-top: 0.2em solid #fff;
}

@-ms-viewport{
width: extend-to-zoom;
zoom: 1.0;
} 
ul {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
width: 10%;
height: 500%;
margin-top: 15em;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 10%;
padding-bottom: 10%;
border-style: solid;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 0.875em;
background: #d6d6d6;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

hopefully someone can help me out with this problem =)

Comment: Basically all your "hamburger" menu is doing is to add the 3 lines icon to your page. It's not a working menu where you can just put some <li>'s in and it will work perfectly fine without any effort. I would suggest you (i think it's the least effort) to have a look at this site and pick you a menu from here which you can add to your page then. http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/5-free-responsive-menus-navigations-for-mobile or this http://www.menucool.com/ddmenu/create-mobile-friendly-responsive-menu

Comment: The "hamburger menu icon" itself is CSS only - creating a function menu that uses the hamburger menu requires **JavaScript**.

Comment: Hi @MarcelWasilewski!

Problem is I have to build the menu, I can't use a finished menu unfortunately..

Comment: @TaniaRascia isn't it at all possible to create a burger menu with only css and html? or at least some other menu that would work on a responsive page?

Comment: Well it is possible creating a mobile menu in CSS only but it's a bit much to explain here how it works. Why can't you take a finished menu? where is the difference? @Viveka

Comment: If you want to make a menu with only HTML and CSS, you're going to need to learn about `@media` queries, and `:hover`.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski well, because this is a school project for a basic class meant to teach you how to code, so anything I want I have to code myself..

Comment: @TaniaRascia well, the course book I have doesn't mention a lot about mediaqueries, but I do have one, which works (hides the burger on big screens, shows it on small)..

Comment: @Viveka I understand, so how i already told you, i think it's a bit much content "just explain it here"... With jquery it would be much easier but you said you can't use it... so maybe getting a finished menu and looking at the code? it could help you doing your own. I would really explain to you but i think it takes some time.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski can you view the code if you download menus from the links above? 
Do you possibly know of any blog/website where I could read about how to do it?

Comment: [I made this tutorial](http://www.taniarascia.com/responsive-dropdown-navigation-bar/) about making a responsive dropdown navigation bar, but it requires jQuery.

Comment: @TaniaRascia and I can't use that =/ maybe I should just forget my idea about the hamburger and try for another kind of menu.. I do know it's possible to get the <select> menu with only css and html, but I think that is pretty ugly =/

Comment: [Here is an example](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/GgLzqJ) of a CSS only menu with Hamburger.

Comment: ohh, I'll have to take a closer look at that, thank you @TaniaRascia !
Not sure I like that the menu covers the entire screen, but it's close enough to what I want, and the size of the "big" menu should be possible to change, shouldn't it?

Comment: [It took me about 20 seconds to do so](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/eJmdPM)

Comment: @TaniaRascia ooh, awesome, thank you so much for your help!!